# I am unable to start ejabberd on ubuntu

Tags: linux, xmpp, ejabberd

The error message is 
Slogan: Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}}},{k
System version: Erlang R16B03 (erts-5.10.4) [source] [64-bit] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

Please help me to get solved.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try to read this [issue](https://www.ejabberd.im/node/872) . It helped me in similar case